# How to Ping List Of Ip AND Host From csv file then register status csv file by Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, output, ping

I have a csv file containing 4 columns
The first and second columns are IP, Host and
The third and fourth column will specify the ping status of each of them
So I need to learn how to ping ip host with powershell and insert the result in the third and fourth columns.
Thanks

$ip = Get-Content -Path D:\PowerShell\hostlist.csv

foreach ( $ip1 in $ip )
{ $ip2 = ping $ip1

if ( $ip2 -imatch "(100% loss)")

{ Write-Host $ip1 " ping is filed " }

else
{ Write-Host $ip1 "ping is success "}
}

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on? Do you have an error message you can post? You probably want to look at ```Import-Csv``` and ```Export-Csv``` to read and write your data respectively…

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please read: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you looking for examples, query e.g.: [`PowerShell ping csv`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PowerShell+ping+csv).

Comment: Use c# which can easily be converted to PS.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.ping?view=net-7.0

Comment: There are literally dozens+ of this sort of thing all over So, the Web, and Youtube. What did you search for from either of the above? ```Write-Host``` is for writing to the screen, not updating a file. ```Set-Content``` or the cmdlets that '@mclayton' provided is the way to do this, and if your Csv does not have proper headers, you can specify them on the read. Get-Content is not proper for the Csv use case for parsing such data. Read your file, get your results, and export those results as a new file. No C# required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment.

Point of note:
The `imatch` thing is not required. Windows is case insensitive by default and thus so is PowerShell. As documented in the PowerShell docs: [about_Case-Sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_case-sensitivity?view=powershell-7.3)

Again, the below is just an example. Refactor as you need to.

FYI...
If your file has no headers. Create them on the read of the file

```
'
127.0.0.1,LP70,,
10.1.1.1,none,,
' | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header IP, Host, Status, Results
# Results
<#
IP        Host Status Results
--        ---- ------ -------
127.0.0.1 LP70               
10.1.1.1  none          
#>
```

Reachability testing by IPAddress

```
'
127.0.0.1,LP70,,
10.1.1.1,none,,
' | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header IP, Host, Status, Results | 
ForEach {Test-Connection -ComputerName $PSItem.IP -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop}
# Results
<#
Source        Destination     IPV4Address      IPV6Address                              Bytes    Time(ms) 
------        -----------     -----------      -----------                              -----    -------- 
LP70          127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1                                                 32       0   
     
Test-Connection : Testing connection to computer '10.1.1.1' failed: Error due to lack of resources
At line:5 char:10
+ ForEach {Test-Connection -ComputerName $PSItem.IP -Count 1 -ErrorActi ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (10.1.1.1:String) [Test-Connection], PingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand
#>
```

Your code, was refactored a bit, and a sample file, with headers

```
IP,Host,Status,Results
127.0.0.1,LP70,,
10.1.1.1,none,,
```

Create a new or overwrite an existing results Csv file

```
New-Item -Path 'D:\Temp' -Name 'hostlistResults.csv'  -ItemType File -Force | 
Out-Null

Import-Csv  -Path 'D:\Temp\hostlist.csv' |
ForEach-Object {
    $Script:Source = $PSItem
    Try 
    {
        "Reachability testiong for $($PSItem.Host)"
        $TestResutlts = Test-Connection -ComputerName $PSItem.IP -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop

       [PSCustomObject]@{
            IP          = $Source.IP
            Host        = $Source.Host
            Destination = $TestResutlts.ProtocolAddress
            Status      = 'Successful'
        } | 
        Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\hostlistResults.csv' -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
    Catch 
    {
        Write-Warning -Message "Reachability testing for $($TestResutlts.PSComputerName) encounterd issues"

       [PSCustomObject]@{
            IP          = $Source.IP
            Host        = $Source.Host
            Destination = 'Not Successful'
            Status      = 'Not Successful'
        } | 
        Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\hostlistResults.csv' -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
}

# Results
<#
Reachability testing for LP70
Reachability testing for none
WARNING: Reachability testing for LP70 encountered issues
#>
```

Review your results via importing.

```
Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Temp\hostlistResults.csv'
# Results
<#
IP        Host Destination    Status        
--        ---- -----------    ------        
127.0.0.1 LP70 127.0.0.1      Successful    
10.1.1.1  none Not Successful Not Successful
#>
```

Comment: In 5.1 you can test them all at once:  `test-connection -AsJob $list | receive-job -wait -auto`